# Get URL referrer when a user clicks on our link on Google

Tags: php

If a user clicks on our webpage on a Google search results page, is there any way of knowing that the user came to our website from Google?

When I run:

```
<?php print_r($_SERVER); ?>
```

I can't see any details about the user coming from Google. Any other options?

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER`... but it cannot really be trusted as not all user agents will set this

Comment: You could also add a query parameter in the url and check it when you receive the request on your server.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER doesn't seem to work @B001ᛦ.

Comment: Also @Juan, how do you mean? We can't edit our listing on Google

Comment: _doesn't seem to work..._ I told you why ;)

Comment: You must tell google which is the url to link to, in that url you can add /?cameFrom=google, then check on your server if there is a query parameter cameFrom and if the value is google.

Comment: Interesting @Juan, do you mean we set some sort of tag on in our website HTML that Google then crawls, or we set it in a Google webmaster console (or similar)?

Comment: I did it for a landing page, but I didn't do the google configuration part. My client did it. But yes it is set on the google side. This is relate to google campaings, I forgot to mention that.